# variable === undefined vs. typeof variable === "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

The [jQuery Core Style Guidelines](https://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/#type-checks) suggest two different ways to check whether a variable is defined.

- Global Variables: `typeof variable === "undefined"`
- Local Variables: `variable === undefined`
- Properties: `object.prop === undefined`

Why does jQuery use one approach for global variables and another for locals and properties?

Comment: I can't answer the question as to why JQuery would use both approaches, but Javascript does have some interesting quirks that mean these two things are subtly different. It shouldn't matter most of the time (ie if your code is sane), but there are differences nevertheless: See here for a write-up - http://wtfjs.com/2010/02/15/undefined-is-mutable

Comment: As @Struppi pointed out, jQuery's outermost function has an argument named undefined. Within jQuery, `foo === undefined` is checking against the local copy of undefined instead of the global (window.undefined), which may have been modified by insane code. The fact that undefined is mutable is definitely worth noting and I'm glad you did. (+1)

Comment: Current link for that article is https://wtfjs.com/wtfs/2010-02-15-undefined-is-mutable

Answer (score 452, accepted):

For undeclared variables, `typeof foo` will return the string `"undefined"`, whereas the identity check `foo === undefined` would trigger the error *"foo is not defined"*.

For local variables (which you *know* are declared somewhere), no such error would occur, hence the identity check.

Comment: @goreSplatter You can't delete it now. :-) It was hard to choose, but the way the question is phrased, this answer is a better fit. Anyone who's interested in how undefined works in general (as I was) should also look at the other answers, especially @Tim's.

Comment: I would add quotation marks (`typeof foo; // -> "undefined"`) to emphasise it is a string and not the primitive value `undefined`.

Comment: I would add, checking for (x !== undefined) would also fail for local function variables, if you declared a "let" or "cont" type AFTER you tried to access it in a function. JavaScript hoists them, but they are in a dead zone, so even this would fail: function MyError(){ if(x !== undefined){console.log(x);} let x = 1;} MyError(); >>> "Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'x' before initialization." This forces developers to declare all their let/const variables at the top, but not after naive developers think they can check for the declared let in a local scope using (x !== undefined).

Answer (score 144):

I'd stick to using `typeof foo === "undefined"` everywhere. That can never go wrong.

I imagine the reason why jQuery recommends the two different methods is that they define their own `undefined` variable within the function that jQuery code lives in, so within that function `undefined` is safe from tampering from outside. I would also imagine that someone somewhere has benchmarked the two different approaches and discovered that `foo === undefined` is faster and therefore decided it's the way to go. **[UPDATE: as noted in the comments, the comparison with `undefined` is also slightly shorter, which could be a consideration.]**  However, the gain in practical situations will be utterly insignificant: this check will never, ever be any kind of bottleneck, and what you lose is significant: evaluating a property of a host object for comparison can throw an error whereas a `typeof` check never will.

For example, the following is used in IE for parsing XML:

```
var x = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
```

To check whether it has a `loadXML` method safely:

```
typeof x.loadXML === "undefined"; // Returns false
```

On the other hand:

```
x.loadXML === undefined; // Throws an error
```

**UPDATE**

Another advantage of the `typeof` check that I forgot to mention was that it also works with undeclared variables, which the `foo === undefined` check does not, and in fact throws a `ReferenceError`. Thanks to @LinusKleen for reminding me. For example:

```
typeof someUndeclaredVariable; // "undefined"
someUndeclaredVariable === undefined; // throws a ReferenceError
```

Bottom line: always use the `typeof` check.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Your point about performance makes sense. The jQuery team is likely more concerned about the impact on file size. `foo === undefined`, when minimized, is probably something like `f===u`, whereas `typeof foo === "undefined"` can only be reduced to `typeof f==="undefined"`.

Comment: You could define `var u = "undefined"` and reduce it to `typeof f==u`, which improves things but is still larger.

Comment: Good points, but I'm not sure the safety of `typeof` against undeclared variables is an advantage. If anything it lets typos slip past more easily, and I can't see when you'd actually want to check the type of undeclared variables.

Comment: @Box9: I can imagine using it in a library to check for the presence of another library.

Comment: @Tim Down, in which case `window.library === undefined` can be used (and the `window` should probably be explicit anyway).

Comment: @Box9: Yes, that's true. I don't think I've ever needed to check for an undeclared variable, so I am struggling for use cases.

Comment: If you are using jslint it will not accept typeof variable === "undefined".

Comment: @jontro: That's one reason not to use JSLint then.

Comment: why did you write `BOOM` on `x.loadXml === undefined`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith: A lighthearted way of saying that an error is thrown in Internet Explorer. I'll change it.

Comment: Thanks @TimDown. And it throws an error since that property `loadXml` is not a member of `x`, right?

Comment: @KevinMeredith: Not exactly: for a native JavaScript object, accessing a non-existent property does not throw an error, but a host object (i.e. one provided by the environment such as a DOM node or ActiveX object) is not subject to the same rules and can do what it likes, inlcuding throwing an error for an innocent property access. The `loadXML` example illustrates this.

Comment: @TimDown If you check document.body.notDefined === undefined, it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: @JohnKurlak: True, although I don't think I've implied that it would.

Comment: @TimDown You said, "evaluating a property of a host object for comparison can throw an error"

Comment: @JohnKurlak: "can" being the operative word.

Comment: According to a quick test case I added on jsperf, saving the 'undefined' string in a variable `undef` and comparing with `typeof f == undef`, this is actually the slowest possible method amongst all listed. Not a good idea! [see jsperf](http://jsperf.com/type-of-undefined-vs-undefined/51)

Comment: @yerforkferchips: Yes, that's possible. However, speed of undefined checks is never going to be a serious concern in practice. Actually I do sometimes use direct comparison with `undefined` these days but not because of performance concerns.

Comment: It always depends on the use case, and you can never know about that in advance - so knowing about possible performance issues is good, right? :)

Comment: Both undefined and 'undefined' have falsy values in JavaScript, so a better way to determine this would be `!foo`, which would return a Boolean.

Comment: In older browsers undefined was mutable,
```undefined = 3```
```console.log(undefined); // 3```
that's why jquery is declaring undefined. to make sure is always going to be undefined.



```(function (undefined) {console.log(undefined); /*undefined*/})();```

Answer (score 34):

Yet another reason for using the typeof-variant: `undefined` can be redefined.

```
undefined = "foo";
var variable = "foo";
if (variable === undefined)
  console.log("eh, what?!");
```

The result of `typeof variable`  cannot.

**Update**: note that this is not the case in ES5 there the global `undefined` is a non-configurable, non-writable property:

> [15.1.1 Value Properties of the Global Object](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1)
>   [...]
>   [15.1.1.3 undefined](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1.3)
>   The value of `undefined` is undefined (see 8.1). This property has the attributes
>   { [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }.

But it still can be shadowed by a local variable:

```js
(function() {
  var undefined = "foo";
  var variable = "foo";
  if (variable === undefined)
    console.log("eh, what?!");  
})()
```

or parameter:

```js
(function(undefined) {
  var variable = "foo";
  if (variable === undefined)
    console.log("eh, what?!");  
})("foo")
```

Comment: Can’t be redefined in ES5.

Comment: The global `undefined` property can't be redefined in ES5, but still can be shadowed with a local variable. `void 0` is shorter and safer.

Comment: I'd say that if your code is redefining undefined then you have bigger problems to deal with than whether to use typeof or not.

Comment: Yes, I agree, one's problems are bigger if the code is redefining undefined.  But that is irrelevant wrt to the concept of Best Practices.

Answer (score 6):

Because `undefined` is not always declared, but jQuery declares `undefined` in its main function. So they use the safe `undefined` value internally, but outside, they use the `typeof` style to be safe.

Answer (score 6):

Who is interested in the performance gain of `variable === undefined`, may take a look here, but it seems to be a chrome optimization only.

- http://jsperf.com/type-of-undefined-vs-undefined/30
- http://jsperf.com/type-of-undefined-vs-undefined

Answer (score 4):

For local variables, checking with `localVar === undefined` will work because they must have been defined somewhere within the local scope or they will not be considered local.

For variables which are not local and not defined anywhere, the check `someVar === undefined` will throw exception: *Uncaught ReferenceError: j is not defined*

Here is some code which will clarify what I am saying above. *Please pay attention to inline comments for further clarity*.

```
function f (x) {
    if (x === undefined) console.log('x is undefined [x === undefined].');
    else console.log('x is not undefined [x === undefined.]');

    if (typeof(x) === 'undefined') console.log('x is undefined [typeof(x) === \'undefined\'].');
    else console.log('x is not undefined [typeof(x) === \'undefined\'].');

    // This will throw exception because what the hell is j? It is nowhere to be found.
    try
    {
        if (j === undefined) console.log('j is undefined [j === undefined].');
        else console.log('j is not undefined [j === undefined].');
    }
    catch(e){console.log('Error!!! Cannot use [j === undefined] because j is nowhere to be found in our source code.');}

    // However this will not throw exception
    if (typeof j === 'undefined') console.log('j is undefined (typeof(x) === \'undefined\'). We can use this check even though j is nowhere to be found in our source code and it will not throw.');
    else console.log('j is not undefined [typeof(x) === \'undefined\'].');
};
```

If we call the above code like this:

```
f();
```

The output would be this:

```
x is undefined [x === undefined].
x is undefined [typeof(x) === 'undefined'].
Error!!! Cannot use [j === undefined] because j is nowhere to be found in our source code.
j is undefined (typeof(x) === 'undefined'). We can use this check even though j is nowhere to be found in our source code and it will not throw.
```

If we call the above code like these (with any value actually):

```
f(null); 
f(1);
```

The output will be:

```
x is not undefined [x === undefined].
x is not undefined [typeof(x) === 'undefined'].
Error!!! Cannot use [j === undefined] because j is nowhere to be found in our source code.
j is undefined (typeof(x) === 'undefined'). We can use this check even though j is nowhere to be found in our source code and it will not throw.
```

---

When you do the check like this: `typeof x === 'undefined'`, you are essentially asking this: *Please check if the variable `x` exists (has been defined) somewhere in the source code.* (more or less). If you know C# or Java, this type of check is never done because if it does not exist, it will not compile.

[<== Fiddle Me ==>](https://jsfiddle.net/ndLb5c7p/)

Answer (score 2):

### Summary:

When at global scope we actually want to return true if the variable is not declared or has the value `undefined`:

```js
var globalVar1;

// This variable is declared, but not defined and thus has the value undefined
console.log(globalVar1 === undefined);

// This variable is not declared and thus will throw a referenceError
console.log(globalVar2 === undefined);
```

Because in global scope we are not 100% sure if a variable is declared this might give us a referenceError. When we use the `typeof` operator on the unknown variable we are not getting this issue when the variable is not declared:

```js
var globalVar1;

console.log(typeof globalVar1 === 'undefined');
console.log(typeof globalVar2 === 'undefined');
```

This is due to the fact that the `typeof` operator returns the string `undefined` when a variable is not declared or currently hold the value `undefined` which is exactly what we want.

---

- With local variables we don't have this problem because we know beforehand that this variable will exist. We can simply look in the respective function if the variable is present.
- With object properties we don't have this problem because when we try to lookup an object property which does not exist we also get the value `undefined`

```js
var obj = {};

console.log(obj.myProp === undefined);
```

Answer (score -1):

**jQuery** probably expects you to be using `let` and `const` variables in functions going forward, which in JavaScript's ES6 2015 design **do NOT allow you to use any local scope (function) `let` or `const` variables until they are declared**. Even hoisting by Javascript does not allow you to even type-check them!

If you try and do that, JavaScript generates an error, unlike with `var` variables which when hoisted creates a declared but uninitialized variable you can type check or check to see if its undefined.

If you declare a `let` or `const` variable in a function, but AFTER trying to access it, `typeof` checks still create a Reference Error in JavaScript! Its *very odd behavior*, and illogical to me why it was designed that way. But that is why jQuery likely sees no use for `typeof` function variable use.  Example:

```
function MyError(){ 

    // WOW! This variable DOES NOT EVEN EXIST, but you can still check its type!
    if(typeof x === 'undefined')
    {
        alert(1);// OK!
    }

    // ERROR!
    // WOW! You cannot even check an existing "let" variable's TYPE in a local function!
    if(typeof y === 'undefined')//REFERENCE ERROR!!
    {
        alert(2);
    }
    // We defined the variable so its hoisted to the top but in a dead zone
    let y = 'test';
}

MyError();

// RESULT
// alert 1 fires but a REFERENCE ERROR is generated from the second alert 2 condition.
```

It is odd above how a non-existing local variable cant be checked using `typeof` for 'undefined', but a declared `let` variable in the function cannot! So this is likely why I would not depend on jQuery to define what is best. **There are *edge cases*.**

### More Weirdness on "undefined" variables in JavaScript

**`undefined` has two different expressions, and three different uses, as follows:

1. **"typeof" and "undefined"** types : Variables that are not declared and do not exist are not assigned anything, but have a "type" of undefined. If you access a variable that does NOT even exist, much less declared or initialized, you will generate a REFERENCE ERROR if you access it, even when testing for the primitive default value of `undefined` which is assigned to declared variables until assigned a value. So checking the "typeof" prevents this error in this one case as follows:

```
    // In this first test, the variable "myVariable1" does not exist yet so creates
    // an error if we try and check if its assigned the default value of undefined!
    if (myVariable1 === undefined) alert(true);// REFERENCE ERROR!

    // Here we can elegantly catch the "undefined" type 
    // of the missing variable and stop the REFERENCE ERROR using "typeof".
    if (typeof myVariable1 === "undefined") alert(true);// true

    // Here we have declared the missing variable and notice its 
    // still an "undefined" type until initialized with a value.
    let myVariable1;
    if (typeof myVariable1 === "undefined") alert(true);// true

    // Lastly, after we assign a value, the type is no longer 
    // "undefined" so returns false.
    myVariable1 = 'hello';
    if (typeof myVariable1 === "undefined") alert(true);// false
```

All objects and types in JavaScript that are accessed but not declared will default to a type of "undefined". So, the lesson here is try and check for the `typeof` first, to prevent missing variable errors!

2. **`undefined` primitive values** : All declared variables not yet assigned a value are assigned in JavaScript the *primitve* of `undefined`. If you have declared a variable, but not initialized it yet, its assigned this default *primitive* type of `undefined`. That is not same as an "undefined" type. The primitive value of `undefined` is a *reserved* value but can be altered, but that's not what is asked here. Notice this catches all declared but uninitialized variables only:

```
    let myVariable3;
    if (myVariable3 === undefined) alert(true);// true

    let myVariable4 = 'hello';
    if (myVariable4 === undefined) alert(true);// false
```

3. **Objects and `undefined` primitives** : Lastly, Object properties do NOT behave like variables in JavaScript. Object properties, when missing do not become undefined types, but are simply assigned the *primitive* `undefined` as above for undeclared variables. So they act like #2:

```
    let myObject = {};
    if (myObject.myProperty === undefined) alert(true);// true
```

### BEST PRACTICE

Lastly....this is a VERY GOOD REASON to always check for BOTH the "undefined" type and the `undefined` *primitive* value on variables in all your JavaScript code. Most will say, you will rarely need both. There may come a day when a missing variable is accessed in a library that does not exist and creates a nasty JavaScript REFERENCE ERROR! So I always do this check, and in this order, to stop all errors in JavaScript:

```
if (typeof myVariable !== "undefined" && myVariable !== undefined) {
    // do something safe with myVariable!
}
```

Answer (score -9):

`typeof a === 'undefined'` is faster then `a === 'undefined'` by about 2 times on node v6.9.1.

Comment: Those are not same things that you typed. I think you meant `undefined` at the second part, not `'undefined'`