# Javascript - Where i'm making a mistake?

Tags: javascript

i'm creating that script if someone delete the text or link on footer of my template it will redirect to my site, but its redirecting without removing anything.

```
function loadBody() {
 var elem = document.getElementById("mycontent");
if(elem.innerHTML !== "MySite" || elem.href !== "http://mysite.com")
  window.location="mysite.com"; 
}
```

here is the footer html

```
 <div id='mycontent'>       
  <p>&#169; Template is designed by  <a href='http://mysite.com' title=''>Mysite</a></p>
  </div>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the footer html?

Comment: Is that because the `href` is in fact `"http://mysite.com"` which causes the second clause of your conditional statement to fail thereby always redirecting?!

Comment: what means !== ?? It shouldn't be != ?

Comment: @anakata It can be either. !== checks type, whereas != does not.
For example, 4!=="4".

Comment: @anakata - type coercion.. read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5101991/1026459

Comment: Just saying that this is really unuseful. If the guy can remove your footer, he can easily remove the script.

Comment: but i will encode my script like other templates designers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because of the structure:

```
function loadBody() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("mycontent");
if(elem.innerHTML !== "MySite" || elem.href !== "http://mysite.com")
    window.location="mysite.com"; 
}

<div id='mycontent'>       
    <p>&#169; Template is designed by  <a href='http://mysite.com' title=''>Mysite</a></p>
</div>
```

You are assuming thag the `a` tag has the `mycontent` id attribute, but it is on the div above it. So, either you change for this:

```
<div>       
    <p>&#169; Template is designed by  <a id='mycontent' href='http://mysite.com' title=''>Mysite</a></p>
</div>
```

Or you have to alter the verification on Javascript.

Comment: But I insist: this is useless. If someone WANTS to wipe this out, he will.

Comment: i will encode the script and i will add style tag on this script if someone delete the script all the stylesheet of template will be deleted

Comment: And what if the guy disables the Javascript of the browser?

Comment: hmmm dontknow more for some bloggers it will work fine my site will got backlins :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget `http://`? + EDIT: use getAttribute. Updated with the new innerHTML

```
function loadBody() {
 var elem = document.getElementById("mycontent");
if(elem.innerHTML != "<p>&#169; Template is designed by  <a href='http://mysite.com' title=''>Mysite</a></p>")
  window.location="mysite.com"; 
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?

Comment: sorry but i remove because of stackover flow i was think link are not allowed