# Coffeescript if variable is undefined in function

Tags: coffeescript

Is there a way to force Coffeescript to always convert

```
if x?
  console.log "hello"
```

to

```
 if (typeof x !== "undefined" && x !== null) {
  console.log("hello");
}
```

The reason I'm asking is because if we have the following:

```
x = "hello"

if x?
  console.log "hello"
```

It gets converted to:

```
var x;

x = "hello";

if (x != null) {
  console.log("hello");
}
```

While this is not a problem in the code above, it is problematic in functions to which an undefined variable is passed.

Answer (score 0):

`x != null` also covers `x != undefined` so the converted code should not be entering the if statement if x is undefined.

See more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5101991/3862007)