# why alert is display in jquery while comparing the values of two variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi can you please tell me why aleert is display when I am comparing the values

**a is undefined** 
and **b is  null** .how they are equal ?
http://jsfiddle.net/4fmzjhge/

```
var a
var b=null;
//value of a
alert(a);
//
alert(b)
if(a==b){alert('test');}

alert(typeof(a));

alert(typeof(b));
```

Comment: use === instead of == and it will work

Comment: yes why == give alert my Question is that == check only value and === check value as well datatype.But both value is different one is null and second is "undefined"

Comment: Read this too for more info :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript

Comment: your answer is very clearly explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101948/javascript-checking-for-null-vs-undefined-and-difference-between-and

Answer (score 0):

because undefined, false, null, 0 is have same level in condition statement it is = false