# What is difference between undefined and null in javascript and what are their usecases?

Tags: javascript

Anyone please tell what is the difference between undefined and null in javascript and when I should use undefined and when null.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101948/javascript-checking-for-null-vs-undefined-and-difference-between-and

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

undefined means a variable has been declared but has not yet been assigned.
null is an assignment value. It can be assigned to a variable as a representation of no value

example.

```
var a;

alert(typeof(a));

var b = null;

alert(typeof(b));
```

Running the above script will result in the following output:

undefined
object

——————————-

Answer (score 0):

`undefined` is not defined at all... means, that given variable does not exist.

`null` is defined variable that has value set to null (so basically you can say that it is defined variable with undefined value)