# if condition not affecting display of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement, nan

I have searched on StackOverflow but no questions matched my specific dilemma. I have a div with a class ***foo*** that is set via css to ***display: inline-block***.

I would like foo to be visible when the variable ***temp*** is a number or a string, but *not display* when it is not a number or a string.

```
var temp;
        if (temp !== undefined || temp !== null) {
            temp = temp / 1000;
            temp = temp + 'K';
            $('.foo').css("display", "inline-block");
        }
        else {
            $('.foo').css("display", "none");
        }
```

When I run this code the "foo" does not display at all.

when I change the code to

```
var temp;
        if (temp != undefined || temp != null) {
            temp = temp / 1000;
            temp = temp + 'K';
            $('.foo').css("display", "inline-block");
        }
        if  (temp == undefined || temp == NaN) {
            $('.foo').css("display", "none");
        }
```

***foo*** is still all set to ***display:"none"***

I ran console.log on each ***if***, and when ***temp*** is a value it does go through the **first** ***if*** and when it is ***NaN*** or *null* it does go through the **second** ***if***. But why does **ONLY** the ***display: "none"*** take affect?

Thank you in advance. - VS

**EDIT**
**Changed code for first if in first code block**

To clarif, ***temp*** is constantly being reset to a new value above this if using a .get function:

```
var temp =this.model.get('custitem_temp');
```

and this value is sucessfully being set multiple times. SOME of my console for reference:

```
temp is set using .get: 80000
temp inside FIRST IF: 80000
temp is set using .get: undefined
temp inside FIRST IF: undefined
temp is set using .get: undefined
temp inside FIRST IF: undefined
temp is set using .get: 80000
temp inside FIRST IF: 80000
temp is set using .get: undefined
temp inside FIRST IF: undefined
temp is set using .get: 80000
temp inside FIRST IF: 80000
temp is set using .get: undefined
```

...

and so on.

***EDIT02:***

Thank you for all your help. So from the suggestions, my code is now dividing **undefined** and ***values***

```
         if (temp === undefined || temp === null) {
            console.log("temp (should be undefined): " + temp)
            console.log("inside IF");;  
            $('.foo').css("display", "none");
         }
         else {
            console.log("temp (should be a value): " + temp)
            console.log("inside ELSE: " + temp);    
            temp = temp / 1000;
            temp = temp + 'K';
            $('.foo').css("display", "inline-block");
            console.log("after ELSE: " + temp);
        }
```

and console reflects:

```
temp (should be a value): 80000
inside ELSE: 80000
after ELSE: 80K
temp (should be undefined): undefined
inside IF
temp (should be undefined): undefined
inside IF
temp (should be a value): 80000
inside ELSE: 80000
after ELSE: 80K
...
```

Nevertheless, I still get **display: none;** on foo

EDIT 03:

I added a console.log to output the display value:

```
            if (temp === undefined || temp === null) {
            console.log("temp (should be undefined): " + temp)
            console.log("inside IF");
            $('.foo').css("display", "none");
            console.log( "display value: " + $('.foo').css('display') );
         }
         else {
            console.log("temp (should be a value): " + temp)
            console.log("inside ELSE: " + temp);    
            temp = temp / 1000;
            temp = temp + 'K';
            $('.foo').css("display", "inline-block");
            console.log("after ELSE: " + temp);
            console.log( "display value: " + $('.foo').css('display') );
        }
```

My console log gives some interesting insight:
Starts off like before, except saying the display value is ***undefined***

```
temp (should be a value): 80000
inside ELSE: 80000
after ELSE: 80K
display value: undefined
temp (should be undefined): undefined
inside IF
display value: undefined
temp (should be undefined): undefined
inside IF
```

but then after about 9 loops it starts assigning a value to display:

```
temp (should be a value): 80000
inside ELSE: 80000
after ELSE: 80K
display value: undefined
temp (should be undefined): undefined
inside IF
display value: none
temp (should be undefined): undefined
inside IF
display value: none
temp (should be a value): 80000
inside ELSE: 80000
after ELSE: 80K
display value: block
temp (should be undefined): undefined
inside IF
display value: none
```

Any explanations?

Comment: where you are assigning value to `temp`?

Comment: Is this wrapped in a `.ready()` function?

Comment: `var temp;` is setting the the value of `temp` as `null`. (unless you assign the value in the between).

Comment: I am assigned value to temp before the if conditions...this is an altered version of a propritary system using NetSuite. The .ready() is not needed, because this is being minified via gulp into a master js file and then being loaded. "temp" gets loaded with values multiple times on the page and this script is to evaluate the display of "foo" on the page.

Comment: `display:none` because 2nd if statement is being satisfied. ie. `temp` is `NaN || undefined`

Comment: @Tareq Mahmood, it's not `null`, it's `undefined` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101948/javascript-checking-for-null-vs-undefined-and-difference-between-and

Comment: @AndrewBrooke, Yap, I just meant to say that, it's equivalent to `null`, so `temp != undefined || temp != null` should be false always.

Comment: Say the if statement returned true, even though it never will. How would one expect `temp = temp / 1000;` to work if `temp` is a string?

Answer (score 2):

Did you check your console? Your second `if` syntax is wrong. It should be like this

```
if (tempMileageWarranty == undefined || tempMileageWarranty == NaN)'
```

Copy paste mistakes aside...

`.foo` is getting set to `display: none;` because `temp` is undefined..

The code `var temp;` is going to make `temp` undefined, (passing your second `if`) because it is never assigned a value.

This might be some useful reading: [JavaScript checking for null vs. undefined and difference between == and ===](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101948/javascript-checking-for-null-vs-undefined-and-difference-between-and)

Comment: Sorry about the syntax, when copying and editing I fudged the second if. I edited it to be correct.

I check the console. when "temp" has a value it goes through my first if and then when it is undefined it goes through the second if. But regradless of temp having a value, it still does not display.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are confused then, it's getting set to `display: none;` because it's undefined..

Comment: But when it is defined it still setting it to display: none...this is evaluating every time temp is being set to a new value via .get method

Comment: Thank you for your fiddle. I guess there is something else not working in my system, because my code is still not working. I am constantly only being sent to the first if...temp being undefined or not. refer to my console.log in OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
t = typeof(temp);   
if(t == "undefined")
{
    console.log(temp +": do not display");  
}
else if(t == 'number' || t == 'string') {
    console.log(temp +": It is "+t+".So display the foo");
}
```

Try this code. I checked it with 3 value of temp.80000,"Foo",undefined and the result I got in console is like this.

```
80000: It is number.So display the foo
foo: It is string.So display the foo
undefined: do not display
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you...so I implemented what you said and I am stlll getting the same resulte, all display:none:
Some of my console log:
++
    80000: It is number. So display the foo / 
    temp (should be a value): 80000 / 
    inside ELSE: 80000 / 
    after ELSE: 80K / 
    display value: undefined / 
    undefined: do not display / 
    temp (should be undefined): undefined / 
    inside IF / 
    display value: undefined / 
    undefined: do not display / 
++
you can see the display css value is "undefined"  That is the part i do not get.

Comment: Are you creating div dynamically ?

Comment: Ok. I asked that because display property of non-existing div is "undefined". If script does find any div, it will return its display prop as undefined. But if you say div is already present, so don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Quick note. Wanted to know if you noticed the double semicolon here.

```
console.log("inside IF");;
```

Also I'd just do a quick and simple check on the defined state if temp and the ensure that it is not null.

```
if (temp && temp !== null) {
         console.log("temp (should be a value): " + temp)
        console.log("inside ELSE: " + temp);    
        temp = temp / 1000;
        temp = temp + 'K';
        $('.foo').css("display", "inline-block");
        console.log("after ELSE: " + temp);
 } else {
        console.log("temp (should be undefined): " + temp)
        console.log("inside IF");
        $('.foo').css("display", "none");
    }
```

Comment: I noticed the double semicolon after i posted it. I corrected that and that did not fix anything. If you look at my last edit of the OP I am checking (and console logging) the display state of foo...it starts out as undefined and then after about 9 iterations it receives a state (block/none)

Comment: instead of the jQuery css functions try the show() hide(). They will achieve the same affect but may be better suited to what you are trying to do. "show for inline-block and hide for none".