# JavaScript - not able to check for null value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm putting together a simple form validation, but I seem to be having an issue with checking for null value in a few of my select elements.  I've abbreviated the option lists in my example below...

```
<select class='species_select' id='species'+siteNumber+'1'>
    <option disabled selected>Select species</option>
    <option value='unknown'>unknown</option>
</select>

<select class='species_select' id='species'+siteNumber+'2'>
    <option disabled selected>Select species</option>
    <option value='unknown'>unknown</option>
</select>

<script>
$(document).on("click", "#next_to_summary", function(){

    var proceed = true;

    $(".species_select").each(function() {

        if (this.value === null){
            alert("Please select the species");
            proceed = false;
        };
});
</script>
```

While experimenting with this, I found that if I assigned a value to the `disabled selected` option and checked for that, the code worked just fine - the alert fired when the select had not been changed.  I'd rather check for null, though...

Am I not checking for null correctly?  Thanks very much.

Comment: `id='species'+siteNumber+'1'`  ???

Comment: Are you sure that the empty value is a null and not a empty ''

Comment: Here is a good thread that talks about null checks in javascript that may be helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27550756/3329778

Comment: Just `if (this.value){` No need of `strict-comparison` as `value` will be `''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, you should rely on $(this).val() to expect null results from non-selected select form fields:

```
 if ($(this).val() === null) {
```

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Thank you!  Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You should not check for null with `===`, but with `==` instead.

As stated in the [null documentation page in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null),

> When checking for null or undefined beware of the [differences between equality (==) and identity (===) operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) (type-conversion is performed with the former).

The strict equality operator (`===`) returns true if the operands are strictly equal (see above) **with no type conversion**. In this case, as `null` is one of JavaScript's primitive values, it is not strictly equal to any other type of object.

After replacing `===` with `==`, your code would then become

```
    if (this.value == null) {
        alert("Please select the species");
        proceed = false;
    };
```

Comment: Ah - thank you. Yes, I see that it is appropriate to use == rather than ===.  However, the code here still didn't work - I needed to use jQuery, as in the answer that I accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code as below :

```
<select class='species_select' id='species'+siteNumber+'1'>
    <option disabled selected value="">Select species</option>
    <option value='unknown'>unknown</option>
</select>

<select class='species_select' id='species'+siteNumber+'2'>
    <option disabled selected value="">Select species</option>
    <option value='unknown'>unknown</option>
</select>

<script>
$(document).on("click", "#next_to_summary", function(){

    var proceed = true;

    $(".species_select").each(function() {

        if ($.trim(this.value) == ""){
            alert("Please select the species");
            proceed = false;
        };
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
if($(this).val() == null || $(this).val() == undefined)
```

Comment: Some explanation would greatly improve this post. Also, because you've used equal (`==`) rather than strict equal (`===`), you only need to check for null, as that will also [return true for undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101948/javascript-checking-for-null-vs-undefined-and-difference-between-and). In general, you should avoid the `==` operator in javascript. It frequently surprises, which is bad.