# Null and Undefined check on a variable at same time

Tags: javascript

I have JavaScript method as below,

```
function showMsg(id) {
 if(id==null && id== undefined)
  //doing some task
}
```

this `showMsg(id)` is getting called from different event with `id` having some value but `onLoad` event its not required any parameter so I am calling this method as below on `Onload` event

```
function onLoading(){
    showMsg(null);
}
```

in Java Script if we have declare a variable and haven't assigned any value to it then it will be undefined.

My question is that is there any situation where  `if(id==null && id== undefined)` will be false when get called as  `showMsg(null);` from `onLoading()` method.

Will it cause any performance issue,and what are the pros and cons for using this  type of check.

Any help suggsetion must be apprecaited Thanks in Advance.

Comment: *"If `id` is `null` __and__ `undefined`"*? At the same time? That's never going to be the case. It only happens to work because you're using a loose `==` comparison, which matches all *falsey* values. You may as well just do `!id` for the same outcome. If you actually want to check for only `null` and `undefined` specifically you'll have to do `id === null || id === undefined`.

Comment: @deceze if i am making call like showMsg(null); in this use case will the condition if(id==null && id== undefined) become false?

Comment: @deceze `===` might break if variable doesn't exist in which, he has to use `typeof`

Comment: @Mr.Alien Since `id` is defined as a function parameter, it will exist. Only its value will be `undefined`.

Comment: @deceze fair enough.. just saying regardless of his code.. just going with the title..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `if(var != null)`.

The `!=` will make both checks: if not `undefined` and not `null`.

Comment: check also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101948/javascript-checking-for-null-vs-undefined-and-difference-between-and