# i want select list value in first list to display in next list

Tags: javascript, html

I want the selected item in the first div to display in the textarea in another div. I wrote some code  but its not working. Please help me out.

```js
function getSelectedOptions(sel, fn) {
  alert("hjgh");
  var opts = [],
    opt;

  // loop through options in select list
  for (var i = 0, len = sel.options.length; i < len; i++) {
    opt = sel.options[i];

    // check if selected
    if (opt.selected) {
      // add to array of option elements to return from this function
      opts.push(opt);

      // invoke optional callback function if provided
      if (fn) {
        fn(opt);
      }
    }
  }

  // return array containing references to selected option elements
  return opts;
}

function callback(opt) {
  alert("tfh");
  // display in textarea for this example
  var display = document.getElementById('display');
  display.innerHTML += opt.value + ', ';

  // can access properties of opt, such as...
  //alert( opt.value )
  //alert( opt.text )
  //alert( opt.form )
}

// anonymous function onchange for select list with id demoSel
document.getElementById('demoSel').onchange = function(e) {
  alert("ghghg");
  // get reference to display textarea
  var display = document.getElementById('display');
  display.innerHTML = ''; // reset

  // callback fn handles selected options
  getSelectedOptions(this, callback);

  // remove ', ' at end of string
  var str = display.innerHTML.slice(0, -2);
  display.innerHTML = str;
};

document.getElementById('demoForm').onsubmit = function(e) {
  alert('hhj');
  // reference to select list using this keyword and form elements collection
  // no callback function used this time
  var opts = getSelectedOptions(this.elements['demoSel[]']);

  alert('The number of options selected is: ' + opts.length); //  number of selected options

  return false; // don't return online form
};
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form action="#" method="post" id="demoForm" class="demoForm">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Demo: Get Selected Options</legend>

        <p>
          <select name="demoSel[]" id="demoSel" size="4" multiple>
                        <option value="scroll">Scrolling Divs JavaScript</option>
                        <option value="tooltip">JavaScript Tooltips</option>
                        <option value="con_scroll">Continuous Scroller</option>
                        <option value="banner">Rotating Banner JavaScript</option>
                        <option value="random_img">Random Image PHP</option>
                        <option value="form_builder">PHP Form Generator</option>
                        <option value="table_class">PHP Table Class</option>
                        <option value="order_forms">PHP Order Forms</option>
                    </select>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          <textarea name="display" id="display" placeholder="view select list value(s) onchange" cols="20" rows="4" readonly></textarea>
        </p>

      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed your  2 uppermost functions with a semi-colon; these seem to be the only errors as far as I can tell. Your code works fine. I commented out the alerts to show the working code (the alerts work but i find them somewhat annoying, you can comment them in again if you like).

Run the snippet to see..

```js
function getSelectedOptions(sel, fn) {
 // alert("hjgh");
  var opts = [],
    opt;

  // loop through options in select list
  for (var i = 0, len = sel.options.length; i < len; i++) {
    opt = sel.options[i];

    // check if selected
    if (opt.selected) {
      // add to array of option elements to return from this function
      opts.push(opt);

      // invoke optional callback function if provided
      if (fn) {
        fn(opt);
      }
    }
  }

  // return array containing references to selected option elements
  return opts;
};

function callback(opt) {
 //alert("tfh");
  // display in textarea for this example
  var display = document.getElementById('display');
  display.innerHTML += opt.value + ', ';

  // can access properties of opt, such as...
  //alert( opt.value )
  //alert( opt.text )
  //alert( opt.form )
};


// anonymous function onchange for select list with id demoSel
document.getElementById('demoSel').onchange = function(e) {
 //alert("ghghg");
  // get reference to display textarea
  var display = document.getElementById('display');
  display.innerHTML = ''; // reset

  // callback fn handles selected options
  getSelectedOptions(this, callback);

  // remove ', ' at end of string
  var str = display.innerHTML.slice(0, -2);
  display.innerHTML = str;
};

document.getElementById('demoForm').onsubmit = function(e) {
  //alert('hhj');
  // reference to select list using this keyword and form elements collection
  // no callback function used this time
  var opts = getSelectedOptions(this.elements['demoSel[]']);

  alert('The number of options selected is: ' + opts.length); //  number of selected options

  return false; // don't return online form
};
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <form action="#" method="post" id="demoForm" class="demoForm">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Demo: Get Selected Options</legend>

          <p>
            <select name="demoSel[]" id="demoSel" size="4" multiple>
                    <option value="scroll">Scrolling Divs JavaScript</option>
                    <option value="tooltip">JavaScript Tooltips</option>
                    <option value="con_scroll">Continuous Scroller</option>
                    <option value="banner">Rotating Banner JavaScript</option>
                    <option value="random_img">Random Image PHP</option>
                    <option value="form_builder">PHP Form Generator</option>
                    <option value="table_class">PHP Table Class</option>
                    <option value="order_forms">PHP Order Forms</option>
                </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            <textarea name="display" id="display" placeholder="view select list value(s) onchange" cols="20" rows="4" readonly></textarea>
          </p>

        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is it ok but am using this code but its not working canot property onchange function error showing

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null
    at demo.php:43  that is the error

Comment: Declare len before the for loop. Also either set a default selected value using selected or check for null. If selected is undefined or null then either alert please select an option or  select the first one.. (alert is better)

Comment: there's an answer here which explains checking for undefined/null https://stackoverflow.com/a/5101991/1675954  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Please accept the answer. Hover and click, it's not hard. See second link!