# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uuid' of undefined in threejs?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new on three.js and I don't understand what does it mean?

I want to show .dae object.

Anybody can help w/ this case?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was in the following line

```
var action = mixer.clipAction( animations[ 0 ] ).play();
```

I used code from example from threejs website and the example was a moving example of a stormtrooper from star wars. But in my example the object is static. So I just removed the line.

Answer (score 10):

Not related, but please note that `uuid` has changed their declare, this one works for me:

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

uuidv4(); // ⇨ '9b1deb4d-3b7d-4bad-9bdd-2b0d7b3dcb6d'
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a three.js error, this is a JavaScript error.
As the error states `Cannot read property 'uuid' of undefined` javascript can not read a property of an undefined variable.

Thus, your `clipObject` is `undefined`.

You may need to read the [JavaScript checking for null vs. undefined and difference between == and ===](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101948/javascript-checking-for-null-vs-undefined-and-difference-between-and)

Comment: It's not the OP's code that is causing this, it seems like its coming from three.js.

Comment: The question was not why the clipObject is undefined :P

Comment: I jumped to a conclusion too early. I figured that with all these checks the thing that was passed should be properly formatted. You are absolutely correct, the OP copied some code, and passed the wrong thing.

Comment: Removed the three.js tag.

Comment: Why? A problem was w/ threejs example

Comment: Your question was not.

Answer (score 0):

To fix error, you need to comment few lines like below (object have`t anim):

const loader = new FBXLoader(); loader.load
(
'files/models/fbx/ContainerBox_05/ContainerBox_05.fbx', function (object)
{
//mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(object); <-- COMMENT THIS

```
    //const <-- COMMENT THIS
                    
    //action = mixer.clipAction(object.animations[0]); <-- COMMENT THIS
    //action.play(); <-- COMMENT THIS
```