# TypeError: Cannot read property of null in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have a React-Select Component which renders a drop-down Menu and when an item from the dropDown is selected a button get´s rendered.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
class selectDemo extends Component {
state = { 
    selectedOption: '',
    data: [
        {Model: 'Option1'},
        {Model: 'Option2'},
    ],
 }

//Handler for Select Drop Down
handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({selectedOption}, ()=>console.log(this.state.selectedOption.Model));
}

RenderButton = () => {           
        return <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">{this.state.selectedOption.Model}</button>
}

render() {
    console.log(this.state.selectedOption);
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    const value = selectedOption && selectedOption.Model;
    return (
        <div>
            <div name="selectedOption" className="section">
                <Select
                    className='form-control'
                    placeholder='Select Option'
                    name="selectedOption"
                    value={value}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    labelKey='Model'
                    valueKey='Model'
                    optionClassName='dropdown-item'
                    options={this.state.data}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="section">
               {this.state.selectedOption.Model && <this.RenderButton/>}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
export default selectDemo;
```

However if I clear the value ,i.e. not choosing another one but clicking the x to remove my selection I get an

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Model' of null

Error at exactly Line 54 where I am actually checking wether the value is 'null' or 'undefined'. I tried with `typeof` , `if` and `switch` statemements after reading:

- [Is there a standard function to check for null, undefined, or blank variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in)
- [JavaScript checking for null vs. undefined and difference between == and ===](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101948/javascript-checking-for-null-vs-undefined-and-difference-between-and)

but this doesn´t work as well.

Comment: Where exactly is the error throwing? There is no Line 54 in your code.

Comment: Sorry, yes I simplified the code t post it here and in my original component it was line 54, now it´s actually here `{this.state.selectedOption.Model && <this.RenderButton/>}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is to provide a check before accessing `Model` since when you deselect an option, `selectedOption` becomes null and you cannot access a property from it.

```
 <div className="section">
       {this.state.selectedOption && this.state.selectedOption.Model && <this.RenderButton/>}
 </div>
```

Comment: Yes thanks that was the issue, I was only looking at ´this.state.selectedOption.Model´ since this was throwing the error

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to originate from your line:

```
{this.state.selectedOption.Model && <this.RenderButton/>}
```

This will work if `selectedOption` has a truthy value. However if has the value of `null`, it doesn't make sense to read `Model` from it. As such, you need to first check if `selectedOption` is truthy before checking `Model`.

You are already doing so at the top of the `render()` method:

```
const value = selectedOption && selectedOption.Model;
```

So you could do:

```
{value && <this.RenderButton/>}
```

---

Alternatively, here is a neat way to solve this issue, especially if the property is many levels deep:

```
(selectedOption || {}).Modal && <this.RenderButton/>
```

This means that if `selectedOption` is falsy you can create a temporary object `{}` so that you *can* try to read `Modal` from it without getting an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot , this answer ist correct as well and a nice alternativ to solve the issue