# javascript - NOT vs NULL with Local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, logical-operators, comparison-operators

So I want to get a variable from local storage.  If it doesn't exist in local storage, then I want to create that variable. I was using `if (x==null)` to see if it existed, then I noticed `if(!x)` has the same result.  Is it ok to use `!` in this situation? I didn't know `!` and `null` are the same here.  Also when checking for null, should I use `===` or is `==` ok?

Here's two examples that give me the same results.

```
<script>
localStorage.clear();

a=localStorage.getItem('a');if (!a) a='hello';
alert(a);

x=localStorage.getItem('x');if (!x) x=0.7;
alert(x);

</script>
```

---

```
<script>
localStorage.clear();

a=localStorage.getItem('a');if (a==null) a='hello';
alert(a);

x=localStorage.getItem('x');if (x==null) x=0.7;
alert(x);

</script>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript checking for null vs. undefined and difference between == and ===](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101948/javascript-checking-for-null-vs-undefined-and-difference-between-and)

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, ! means "falsy" and if a value doesn't exist in local storage, it is NULL.  And since null is a falsy value, it would be perfectly acceptable to use if (!x) in this situation, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem

`localStorage.getItem` returns null if the key doesn't exist. So `a === null` would be the most specific check for if the key didn't exist. However, null is falsy in javascript. So you could reduce the check to this:

`a = localStorage.getItem('a') || 'hello';`

Which functions the same as your if with the not operator

Comment: Great answer I didn't know you could use the "or" symbol in this way.   Very good!

Answer (score 0):

Is not exactly the same... This `!x` is checking for a truthy value but anything between `null`, `undefined`, or even `0` will return `false`.

There is also a significant difference between `==` and `===` where `==` will try an automatic type conversion in order to check if the values are in some way compatible, but the `===` will check for an strict equality.

You can learn more about the JavaScript types and their interaction with the different operators in this link [Values, Types, and Operators](https://eloquentjavascript.net/01_values.html)