# Turn Array Into String, Separate String With Separator - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, separator

Define a function, `myJoin`, that accepts up to two arguments:

1. `array`
2. `separator` (string, optional)

`myJoin` should return a string with all of the elements from the array joined together. The separator should separate the joined elements:

```
myJoin(['a', 'b', 'c'], '+'); // => "a+b+c"
```

If separator is undefined, use `','` as the default separator.

```
myJoin(['Peter', 'Paul', 'Mary']); // => "Peter,Paul,Mary"
```

If any elements in the array are `undefined` or `null`, they should be replaced with an empty string in the returned string.

```
myJoin(['hello', undefined, 'world'], '-'); // => "hello--world"
```

I can't use the built-in [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method.

[Link to codepen for testing](https://codepen.io/FullstackAcademy/pen/ZxWLBV?editors=0010)

So far I have tried:

```
function myJoin (array, separator) {

  let newString = "";

  if (separator = undefined) {
    separator === ",";
  }

  else {

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      newString = i + separator;
    }

  }

  newString = array.toString();

  return newString;

}

console.log(myJoin(['a', 'b', 'c'], '+'));
```

^ This is not combining the elements of the string together with the separator, and is actually returning `a,b,c` twice. Any idea why?

**EDIT**: First update to code after @Jonas Wilms' suggestions:

```
function myJoin (array, separator) {

  let newString = "";

  if (separator === undefined) {
    separator === ",";
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newString += array[i] + separator;
  }

  return newString;

}
```

This seems to be working in my VS Code console but not in the CodePen.

Comment: Can you explain your code?

Comment: The `for` loop should not be in the `else` clause, and the comparison in the `if` test should be `==` not `=` (`=` is for *assignment*).

Comment: Sure I'm trying to say, if separator is defined, loop through the array to create a `newString` with the items in the array (`i`) + the `separator`. Then turn `newString` into a string and return it.

Comment: The code `if (separator = undefined)` is doing an assignation of variable separator to `undefined` value,  not a comparison as you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function myJoin(array, separator=',') {
  let str = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] !== null && array[i] !== undefined)
      str += array[i];
    if (i < array.length - 1)
      str += separator;
  }

  return str;
}

console.log(myJoin(['a','b','c']));
console.log(myJoin(['a','b','c'], '+'));
console.log(myJoin(['a',null,'c'], '-'));
console.log(myJoin(['a','b',undefined], '.'));
```

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand the use of `...params` as the parameter. Can you please rewrite it with the parameters `array`, `separator` like in my code?

Comment: @HappyHands31 ...params takes all the parameters and form an array with it. But now it's even easier to understand with the two parameters

Comment: Thank you - yeah now it's making sense, and it works. So then with your two `if-statements`, it's alternating between appending `array[i]` and `separator` to the `str`? Do `if-statements` alternate what they append by default then?

Comment: Also can you please explain `separator=','` as the initial second parameter - what if the user enters separator as `+` or `--`?

Comment: The first `if` checks if your value deserves to be appened to the string (not null and not undefined). The second `if` checks that if we are at the last item of the array, we don't put the separator (avoid having the separator at the end)

Comment: separator=',' means "default value". Thus if you give only one parameter, separator will be set to ','. If you give 2 params, the ',' will be overriden by your 2nd param

Comment: I see, yes I understand what they're checking for - I just did not know that consecutive `if-statements` alternate what they append to a new string. Interesting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191068/discussion-between-davalres-and-happyhands31).

Answer (score 6):

try

```
array.reduce( (s,x,i) => s+(i>0 ? separator : '') + (x==null ? '' : x), '')
```

```js
function myJoin(array, separator=',') { 
  return array.reduce( (s,x,i) => s+(i>0 ? separator : '') + (x==null ? '' : x), '') 
}

console.log( myJoin(['a', 'b', 'c'], '+') ); 
console.log( myJoin(['Peter', 'Paul', 'Mary']) );
console.log( myJoin(['hello', undefined, 'world'], '-') );
```

We use here standard js functionalities: [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [array reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). If `i>0` (not true only for first element) we add separator to output string `s`. If `x` is [undefined or null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55822324/860099) we add to `s` empty string - or `x` value in other case.

Answer (score 2):

A few hints:

- Don't mix up the assignment (`=`) and comparison (`===`) operators. `if(a = b)` is a mistake in 99% of the cases.
- `array.toString()` does call `array.join()` internally, I'd consider that as cheating, also I'm not sure what you want to achieve with that (I mean `newString` should already contain the wanted result if you do the loop correctly, shouldn't it?)
- `i` is the index in your `array` to get the *value* at that position use `array[i]`.
- I don't think that your loop should be in the `else {` branch, I don't think you need that `else` at all (as you always want to join the array by looping over it).
- with `newString =` you *reassign* `newString` and loose the previous value, you might want to use `newString +=` to *append* a value to it.

Comment: Please check out my most recent edit - I've tried to build off of as many of your hints as possible.

Comment: @happyHands31 you also add a seperator to the last item, resulting in "a,b,c," ...

Comment: So I would need to remove the last item from the array that I return? Using `.pop()` or `.slice()`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` and `forEach` with a template string like so:

```js
function myJoin(arr, sep = ",") {
  arr = arr.map(e => [undefined, null].includes(e) ? "" : e);
  var result = "";
  arr.forEach((e, i) => result += `${i ? sep : ""}${e}`);
  return result;
}

console.log(myJoin(['Peter', undefined, 'Paul', null, 'Mary', 'Jack'], "-"));
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
function myJoin(arr, sep) {
  sep = sep || ",";
  arr = arr.map(function(e) {
    return [undefined, null].includes(e) ? "" : e;
  });
  var result = "";
  arr.forEach(function(e, i) {
    result += (i ? sep : "") + e;
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(myJoin(['Peter', undefined, 'Paul', null, 'Mary', 'Jack'], "-"));
```

Comment: `Do not use the built-in .join array method in your answer.`

Comment: Fixed it @Keith.

Answer (score 2):

Use default syntax to set the seperator `||` 
The a `forEach` taking in `value`, `index`, `array`
Test for last element.

```js
function myJoin (array, separator) {
  let newString = "";
  separator = separator||','; 
  
  array.forEach((a,i,arr) => {
    newString += `${a}${(i < arr.length-1) ? separator : ''}`;
  });
  return newString;
}

console.log(myJoin(['a', 'b', 'c'], '+'));
console.log(myJoin(['a', 'b', 'c']));
console.log(myJoin(['a', 'b', 'c'], '-'));
```

Comment: Why would a working piece of code get a down vote without comment?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to join your array.

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', undefined, 'c', 'd', null, 'e'];

myJoin = (arr, separator = ',') =>
  arr.reduce((acc, val, i) =>
    acc + ([undefined, null].indexOf(val) >= 0 ? '' : val) +
    (i < arr.length - 1 ? separator : ''), "");

console.log('myJoin(arr): ', myJoin(arr));
console.log('myJoin(arr, "+"): ', myJoin(arr, '+'));
console.log('arr.join("+"): ', arr.join('+'));
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Using an array to check wether a value is either `null` or `undefined` is a bit overkill IMHO. `val == null` is just fine as `undefined` and `null` are loosely equal to each other.

Comment: @customcommander Yeah, I know, just force of habit by now I guess :/

Answer (score 1):

One can use [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```
let arr = [{id: 1, desc: 'desc1'}, {id: 2, desc: 'desc2'}];
let serialized = arr.map(x => JSON.stringify(x)).join('---');
console.log(serialized);
```

> {"id":1,"desc":"desc1"}---{"id":2,"desc":"desc2"}