# "obj != null" vs "! (obj == null)"?

Tags: javascript, performance, comparison

A friend said I should use `! (obj == null)`, because it's better than `obj != null`, but he didn't remember why to do this.

Is there any reason for using `! (obj == null)`?

Is there any difference? I mean, both should return `true` when the `obj` is not `null` and neither `undefined`, is that right or not? (I am a little confused)

And when the answer is both result to the same, then I would like to know, is that right for all JavaScript versions? (I mean, both work on all browsers or not?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any reason for using ! (obj == null)?

Some people may find it easier (or harder) to read.

> is there any change, I mean, both should return true when the obj is not null and neither undefined, is that right or not? (I am a little confused)

No. They mean exactly the same thing.

> And when the answer is both result to the same, then I would like to know, is that right for all java-script versions? (I mean, both work on all browsers or not?)

Yes.

Comment: thanks, I also found some other useful posts, like [difference between == and ===](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101948/javascript-checking-for-null-vs-undefined-and-difference-between-and/5101991) which I would like to link here...

Answer (score -1):

The `! (obj == null)` will have to perform a comparison operation as well as a boolean operation. So, it is bit slower.

On the other hand, `obj != null` is a single comparison.

The fastest is `obj !== null` which doesn't have to do type coercion.

However, the change of performance of above three cases in average programs are insignificant.

Comment: This answer is therefore also *insignificant* ... I also doubt that this statement is actually true (that there is actually any difference in the JITed code).

Comment: "This answer is therefore also insignificant" - nice logic ;). // I also doubt that this statement is actually true - Go ahead and do a simple performance test.