# Check if a key exists inside a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

```
amt: "10.00"
email: "sam@gmail.com"
merchant_id: "sam"
mobileNo: "9874563210"
orderID: "123456"
passkey: "1234"
```

The above is the JSON object I'm dealing with. I want to check if the `merchant_id` key exists. I tried the below code, but it's not working. Any way to achieve it?

```
<script>
window.onload = function getApp()
{
  var thisSession = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>');
  //console.log(thisSession);
  if (!("merchant_id" in thisSession)==0)
  {
    // do nothing.
  }
  else 
  {
    alert("yeah");
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is the output of `<?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>`?

Comment: Its out put is what I have shown at the top of my question,the json object

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(thisSession);`?

Comment: Also what is the benefit of using `!("merchant_id" in thisSession)==0` where you can simply use `"merchant_id" in thisSession`?

Comment: What is more it will alert "yeah" when "merchant_id" IS in thisSession. Also syntax error in `alert "yeah";`, it should be `alert("yeah")`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a key exists in a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object)

Comment: The code in question contains a triple-negative in the logic (`!`,`==0`,`else`).

Comment: @nobar you may please proceed to those duplicates. 191 people found this useful!

Answer (score 774):

Try this

```
if (thisSession.hasOwnProperty("merchant_id")) {

}
```

the JS Object `thisSession` should be like

```
{
  amt: "10.00",
  email: "sam@gmail.com",
  merchant_id: "sam",
  mobileNo: "9874563210",
  orderID: "123456",
  passkey: "1234"
}
```

you can  find the details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Comment: For edification, what, if any, is the difference between `if(thisSession.merchant_id !== undefined)` and `if(thisSession.hasOwnProperty('merchant_id'))` or is it doing the same thing behind the scenes?

Comment: @zero298, both are not same, using hasOwnProperty is safe ...more more details please check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895288/undefined-typeof-undefined-hasownproperty

Comment: Eslint throws the error `error  Do not access Object.prototype method 'hasOwnProperty' from target object  ` when using this method. Thoughts?

Comment: @hamncheez If JSON has 'hasOwnProperty' field, it will shadow the original func. Use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(thisSession, 'merchant_id')`

Comment: 2023 update: `hasOwnProperty` is no longer recommended (except to support older browsers).  As I describe in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77656009/1261335 , if you are targeting modern browsers / node versions, that function is considered obsolete and you should prefer `hasOwn`.

Answer (score 107):

There's several ways to do it, depending on your intent.

`thisSession.hasOwnProperty('merchant_id');` will tell you if thisSession has that key itself (i.e. not something it inherits from elsewhere)

`"merchant_id" in thisSession`  will tell you if thisSession has the key at all, regardless of where it got it.

`thisSession["merchant_id"]` will return false if the key does not exist, or if its value evaluates to false for any reason (e.g. if it's a literal `false` or the integer 0 and so on).

Comment: thisSession["merchant_id"] will return undefined not false.

Comment: Ok, "falsy" then.

Answer (score 42):

(I wanted to point this out even though I'm late to the party)
The original question you were trying to find a 'Not IN' essentially.
It looks like it is not supported by the research (2 links below) that I was doing.

So if you wanted to do a 'Not In':

```js
    ("merchant_id" in x)
    true
    ("merchant_id_NotInObject" in x)
    false
```

I'd recommend using the **!** operator

```js
    if (!("merchant_id" in thisSession))
    {
        // do nothing.
    }
    else 
    {
        alert("yeah");
    }
```

https://linuxhint.com/use-not-in-operator-javascript/

Answer (score 36):

you can do like this:

```
if("merchant_id" in thisSession){ /** will return true if exist */
 console.log('Exist!');
}
```

or

```
if(thisSession["merchant_id"]){ /** will return its value if exist */
 console.log('Exist!');
}
```

Comment: Works perfect on Node

Comment: Note, the second option will not work for falsey values (e.g. null, undefined, 0).

Answer (score 26):

Type check also works :

```
if(typeof Obj.property == "undefined"){
    // Assign value to the property here
    Obj.property = someValue;
}
```

Comment: typeof did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 16):

This code causes esLint issue: `no-prototype-builtins`

```
foo.hasOwnProperty("bar")
```

The suggest way [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins) is:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(foo, "bar");
```

Answer (score 9):

I change your if statement slightly and works (also for inherited obj - look on snippet)

```
if(!("merchant_id" in thisSession)) alert("yeah");
```

```js
var sessionA = {
  amt: "10.00",
  email: "sam@gmail.com",
  merchant_id: "sam",
  mobileNo: "9874563210",
  orderID: "123456",
  passkey: "1234",
}

var sessionB = {
  amt: "10.00",
  email: "sam@gmail.com",
  mobileNo: "9874563210",
  orderID: "123456",
  passkey: "1234",
}


var sessionCfromA = Object.create(sessionA); // inheritance
sessionCfromA.name = 'john';


if (!("merchant_id" in sessionA)) alert("merchant_id not in sessionA");
if (!("merchant_id" in sessionB)) alert("merchant_id not in sessionB");
if (!("merchant_id" in sessionCfromA)) alert("merchant_id not in sessionCfromA");

if ("merchant_id" in sessionA) alert("merchant_id in sessionA");
if ("merchant_id" in sessionB) alert("merchant_id in sessionB");
if ("merchant_id" in sessionCfromA) alert("merchant_id in sessionCfromA");
```

Answer (score 0):

### function to check undefined and null objects

```
function elementCheck(objarray, callback) {
        var list_undefined = "";
        async.forEachOf(objarray, function (item, key, next_key) {
            console.log("item----->", item);
            console.log("key----->", key);
            if (item == undefined || item == '') {
                list_undefined = list_undefined + "" + key + "!!  ";
                next_key(null);
            } else {
                next_key(null);
            }
        }, function (next_key) {
            callback(list_undefined);
        })
    }
```

here is an easy way to check whether object sent is contain undefined or null

```
var objarray={
"passenger_id":"59b64a2ad328b62e41f9050d",
"started_ride":"1",
"bus_id":"59b8f920e6f7b87b855393ca",
"route_id":"59b1333c36a6c342e132f5d5",
"start_location":"",
"stop_location":""
}
elementCheck(objarray,function(list){
console.log("list");
)
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use *lodash* library

```
import _ from 'lodash';

if(_.isEmpty(merchant_id)){
    // do nothing
}
else{
    //do something with merchant id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript changes once again!

(TL;DR: Use `Object.hasOwn` now.)

The long standing highest-voted answer recommends using `hasOwnProperty`.  This was the best answer at the time, but it does have a number of tricky bits that can trip you up.  For example, if the variable can be `null`, this will cause a TypeError when you attempt to call `hasOwnProperty`.  Less commonly (but a symptom of the same problem), if an object could potentially have a key named "hasOwnProperty," that would shadow the function you wanted.  (This could be a problem if, for example, you are parsing user-provided input.)

Because of all that, the previously correct way to call the function is this mess:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(thisSession, "merchant_id");
```

In updated browsers and recent versions of node there is a new alternative that addresses these problems.  `Object` now has a static method named `hasOwn` that addresses these pitfalls.

```
Object.hasOwn(thisSession, "merchant_id")
```

Ahh, much better.  :)

If you are targeting browsers or node versions new enough to have `hasOwn`, you should stop using `hasOwnProperty` entirely.  It is obsolete.

Answer (score -16):

You can try `if(typeof object !== 'undefined')`

Comment: You can surely try, but it won't do much.