# Underscore, check if key exists in array of objects

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

I am trying to check new data I am receiving against an object I am holding onto, and what I am trying to find out is if they key of the object I am being send matches any keys in the object I currently have.

So I am holding onto an object like

```
myObj = [{"one": 1}, {"two": 2 },{"three" : 3}];
```

And I get sent a single object like

```
{"three" : 5 }
```

And I want to just check this object against the array of objects (myObj) and see if there is anything with the key "three" inside of it ( I don't care about the values, just the key matching) so I can pop it into an if statement to separate like -

```
if( array of objects (myObj) has key from single object ( "three" ) ) {}
```

I am using underscore. Thanks!

Edit : Sorry this was not clear, I am editing it to clarify -

I am holding onto myObj (the array of objects), and being sent a single object - the "three" for example, and I just want to pull that single object key out (Object.keys(updatedObject)[0]) and check if any of the objects in the object array have that key.

So _has seems like it is just for checking a single object, not an array of objects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a key exists inside a json object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804163/check-if-a-key-exists-inside-a-json-object)

Comment: Google "javascript check if key exists in object" returns three relevant results.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv: not a duplicate at all. Its `underscore.js`

Comment: Not a duplicate, this regards using underscore, maybe we should remove the javascript tag to avoid confusion

Comment: The only reason anyone would use anything other than hasOwnProperty would be browser support, right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're looking for the [`_.some` iterator](http://underscorejs.org/#some) combined with a callback that uses [`_.has`](http://underscorejs.org/#has):

```
if (_.some(myObj, function(o) { return _.has(o, "three"); })) {
    …
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use underscore method 'has'

Here the example:

```
_.has({"three" : 5 }, "three");
=> true
```

From the [underscore doc](http://underscorejs.org/#has):

> Does the object contain the given key? Identical to
>   object.hasOwnProperty(key), but uses a safe reference to the
>   hasOwnProperty function, in case it's been overridden accidentally.

Comment: This is on the right track - however it is not checking if the array of objects has "three".