# Check if Element Present in a JS Object

Tags: javascript

I want to check if an "key" is present in a JS object. Is there a way of doing this? +the data can be an arbitrary subbranch within sometree

Example:

```
var sometree = {
    foo : {
        data : 1
    },
    foo2 : {
        data : 5
    }
}

function checkForKey(key, obj) {
    //If I do "checkForKey(5, sometree)", I want the function
    //to return "sometree.foo2.data".
}
```

Comment: 5 seems like value rather than key name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a key exists inside a json object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804163/check-if-a-key-exists-inside-a-json-object)

Comment: Not a duplicate of that one. I edited your question to have a better name for the function.

Comment: Are you needing the `value` you are checking for to also work with sub-objects, or just simple values?

Comment: @AndrewTempleton Why isn't it a duplicate? It seems pretty clear cut to me.

Comment: Because (1) this is a deep check (more than one hop into the object) and (2) He phrased the question poorly, but he's REALLY asking, based on the actual code sample "given a value and an object, tell me the (potentially multi-step) PATH to the value in an object"

Comment: See Anik's comment, he's referring to the same "your code asks a good question but the English needs updating" dilemma.

Comment: 1) It's not a *variable* deep check. 2) Too many answers possible because some people comprehend it as a deepcheck and also see the return value as a string or as the value of the key. Voting this as duplicate therefore.

Comment: ^^^ This makes literally no sense - `theFunc(5, sometree) => "sometree.foo2.data"` is the example he poses right in the question!

Comment: Perhaps the OP can chime in sometime and clarify a few of these things?

Comment: Agree with TbWill4321, downvoting b/c still unclear and OP has not clarified despite timely requests for clarification.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need something recursive if the object can be an arbitrary depth:

```js
    var sometree = {
        foo: {
            data: 1
        },
        foo2: {
            data: 5
        }
    }

    function checkForValue( value, json, name ) {
        var result = checkObject( value, json );
        return result ? name +'.'+ result : null;
    }

    function checkObject( value, json ) {
        var keys = Object.keys(json);
        for ( var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++ ) {
            var key = keys[i];
            if ( typeof json[key] === 'object' && json[key] !== null ) {
                var result = checkObject( value, json[key] );
                if ( result )
                    return key +'.'+ result;
            }
            else if ( json[key] === value ) {
                return key;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    document.write( checkForValue( 5, sometree, 'sometree' ) );
```

Comment: Breaks if anything has `'.'` within the key.

Comment: It doesn't break, there was no specification on how to handle a `.` in key names.  It does return the expected string, and if dots need escaping that can be handled in another question.

Comment: You also don't address the fact that he can't recover the `sometree` / input variable identifier. I mean, we can argue about it, but there's shortcomings in it, and given that this is beginner question, I would imagine it's dangerous to give him code that definitely doesn't do what he wants in one aspect and probably doesn't in another...

Comment: Fixed the issue of missing input variable name.

Answer (score -2):

Following should work:

```
function checkForKey(key, json) {
    var found = false;
    for(var x in json) {
        if (json.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
            if(json[x][data] == key) {
                found = key;
            }
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Comment: He never sayed it was, I assumed he wanted to check the data keys inside the foo keys...Thanks for the downvote

Comment: You also reference `data` herein - It's broken code and doesn't go down 2 levels into the object, I am sorry if the downvote offends you.

Comment: Since data is the subkey of every foo in his json object...he never stated it had more levels and that it had keys besides data in the question...My code isn't broken therefore...

Comment: He means it's broken because `[data]` checks the variable `data`, your code would function as `['data']` instead.

Comment: Oh I typed the quotes though  but somehow they disappeared :/ Seems typing code on my phone is a bad idea.

Answer (score -2):

The `getDeepKeyForValue` function can be implemented either in "just give me one" form or "give me all of them". You could also ask this to support complex objects, but I wrote the ones to support simple values. NOTE: because keys can have `'.'` in them, I return an `Array` of the key path and let you handle those corner cases. You also can't recover the `sometree` identified/variable name from within the function. This will work...:

```js
   function getDeepKeyForValue (value, object, path) {
    var keySet = Object.keys(object || {});
    var key;
    var result;
    path = path || [];
    keySetLength = keySet.length;
    while (keySetLength--) {
        key = keySet[keySetLength];
        if (value === object[key]) {
            return path.concat(key);
        }
        result = getDeepKeyForValue(value, object[key], path.concat(key));
        if (result) {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hey never stated that it was deepkey value :P So this might be overkill and only recommended when it's actually needed. This SO question is becoming kinda http://needsmorejquery.com xD

Comment: Yeah, he did... As in, directly in the question, `sometree.foo2.data` is a deep path / greater than one hop into the object...

Comment: He never stated it was a variable depth and data was a variable. So it's a single depth object with the values wrapped in a object called data.

Comment: Are we reading the same question?? Read the example comments in the code,  and you can clearly see he is passing in the compound object `sometree` looking for a 2-deep value...

Comment: Yeah but you assume that 2 deep can be 3 deep or 4 deep and that data can be hello which is not stated in the question. A deep search makes only sense when the object layout is unknown but we do know that it's only 2 deep and that the second depth keys are called data.