# How can I check if firebase payload data key and value exists

Tags: json, angular, typescript, firebase, ionic2

I am trying to configure my app to redirect according to the payload data, if post_id or page_id or no payload different redirects for these three payloads.

Here is what I am getting in push details:

[image: Push message response]

In above image you can see there is a payload data **post_id** with some value it can be **page_id** for sometime, so I need to check if the key is **post_id** or **page_id** in the payload data and if yes then if the value is null or not.

I tried:

```
pushPayload.indexOf('post_id') !== -1 
parseInt(pushPayload['post_id']) > 0
msg.payload.hasOwnProperty('post_id')
```

but nothing worked.

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a key exists inside a json object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804163/check-if-a-key-exists-inside-a-json-object)

Comment: I already tried the solution but that shows an error....and in that question keys were static and for me it can be different like post_id or page_id

Comment: is this the return of a fcm push? Can you post the entire JSON it's returning?

Comment: yeah the above screen shot is PUSH response excluding (I received awesome push: ), sorry I can not copy paste it as text I am showing it in alert box.