# How can I check if there is variable in json object

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js, fs

I'm trying to check if a guildID is in my JSON object. I got all stuff parsed and done, but I just don't know how to check it.

```
{
  "893782530879258635": {
  
   }
}
```

Expected output: True

```
{
 
}
```

Expected output: False

Comment: Have you seen <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804163/check-if-a-key-exists-inside-a-json-object>?

Comment: Yes but that's not working

Comment: You are trying `guildId in yourFile`? Make sure there are no quotes around the guild id variable

Comment: There is no guildId variable the file is just like I said when I want the function to return false