# Check if the value of a variable exists in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I have a Typescript project where I need to know if the value of a variable is in any property of the Object.

This is the object:

```
let listDump = [
   {
     "properties":{
        "title":"CARS"
     }
  },
  {
     "properties":{
        "title":"HOME"
     }
  },
  {
     "properties":{
        "title":"COUNTRY"
     }
  }
];
```

This is the declared variable:

```
let newData = 'ANIMALS'
```

This is what I do to check if it exists:

```
for (let sheet of listDump) {
  if (sheet.properties.title == newData) {
    console.log(`do not create property`)
  } else {
    console.log('create property') 
  }
}
```

**Problem**: Doing three checks operates three times on the else

What I need to know is how to check that it exists without needing to iterate over the object and operate only once in case it doesn't exist

Comment: Try using `.some`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a key exists inside a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804163/check-if-a-key-exists-inside-a-json-object)

Comment: @SørenEriksen that checks for keys, not values

Comment: Sorry, a bit too quick there

Comment: @stark, you can't get away from iterating over the array. At least `some` will stop at the first match.

Comment: @Andy i think they just wanted a clean way to avoid logging 3 times

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`<Array>.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
listDump.some(sheet => sheet.properties.title == newData) // returns true | false
```

Comment: I have changed the value of the variable, now it is in the JSON object. When I do `listDump.some(sheet => sheet.properties.title == fileName)` out `true`, but when I do `listDump.some(sheet => sheet.properties.title != fileName)` it comes out `true` too, why does this happen? How can I change the condition so that they are different?

Comment: first one checks if any element has a title equal to filename, second checks if any element has a title other than filename ---- if you want to check if every element has a title other than filename replace `some` with `every` on the 2nd statement or add a not `!` to the beginning of the 1st statement