# Class constructor optional arguments in object

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, default-arguments, optional-arguments

Originally I had it as, the error was that c was undefined.

```
constructor(c){
        this.x = c.x || 0;
        this.y = c.y || 0;
        ...
}
```

I tried doing this as well (as suggested by [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735855/javascript-function-with-optional-parameters-as-object)), the error is that the values always get set to default.

```
constructor({
        x = 0,
        y = 0
        } = {}){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        ...
}
```

[Link to Github repo](https://github.com/KellyTJ/particle-system/tree/KellyTJ-patch-1)

Comment: So you need to test if c is an object before you read its property Question is, why would you pass in undefined to it and not with a default empty object.

Comment: `this.x = c?.x || 0;` or set a default for c