# Javascript ?: notation as an argument or parameter

Tags: javascript, java, android, google-maps

I'm looking at the Google Maps Javascript API and I've come across this:

```
LatLng   computeOffset(from:LatLng, distance:number, heading:number, radius?:number)
```

The above method comes from the Google Maps Javascript API documentation at: [Maps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference)

It works without inserting the last argument radius?:number.

My question is what is radius?:number. Is this some conditional statement for an argument? Is this some ternary argument?

The Android Maps API has a similar function without the radius?:number argument:

```
static LatLng computeOffset(LatLng from, double distance, double heading)
```

What is ?: in this context and how is it used?

Comment: I'd guess it means that radius is optional.

Comment: Java? JavaScript? These are two different languages. What are you asking about? ...in any case, the code isn't JavaScript, so the question doesn't make much sense. Give some actual reference to what you're seeing.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't look like a ternary operation. It's just the _documentation_ indicating the radius is optional, like @m69 says.

Comment: @squint This is from the Google Maps Javascript API so Javascript. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this thread about option parameters in javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797118/how-can-i-declare-optional-function-parameters-in-javascript in resume, the required parameters come first then the optionals. The ? in the function declaration is a convention in the docs (it's not a javascript pattern) to say that the param is optional.

Comment: @squint it comes from the spherical namespace list of methods found at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference . The question mark is used in several other methods. I assume from the other comments it is just the documentations way of stating that the parameter is optional.

Answer (score 0):

The radius defaults to the Earth's radius in meters. if you change it to miles answer will be in miles.