# Optional parameters in function

Tags: javascript, optional-parameters, default-parameters

Is it possible to not define function parameters and use a default value in that case?

For example.

```js
function nutrition_facts(calories = 0, fat = 0, carb = 0, protein = 0) {
  cal += calories;
  f += fat;
  carbohydrate += carb;
  p += protein;
}

// Usage.
nutrition(calories = 10, protein = 10);
```

calories and protein would be passed in as 10, and fat and carb would be passed in as 0.

Comment: why can't you refer this.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12797135/3164682

Comment: Because I don't know what ES6 is and if that applies to me.

Comment: @Roger ECMAScript 5/6 is the latest JavaScript standard. Most browsers support it now. It introduces [true class OOP structures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) and allows you to use lambda functions (`=>`). ES6 introduced the ability to have default parameters. See the link in the previous comment. Here's an [ES6 browser compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

Comment: Here are the various browser implementations and which version they are using: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#Implementations As you can see, most browsers are running a stable ES5 implementation. Chrome and Firefox both use ES6 as their baseline.

Answer (score 0):

it IS possible when using ES2015(ES6) or TypeScript.
In your example seems like you use ES5, so it's not possible