# typeof a === 'undefined'

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [variable === undefined vs. typeof variable === “undefined”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725603/variable-undefined-vs-typeof-variable-undefined)

Assuming that `undefined` has not been tampered with, are the following equivalent?

```
typeof a === 'undefined'
```

and

```
a === undefined
```

?

[The reason I ask is because the author of [Parsley.js](https://raw.github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/master/parsley.js) seems to love writing `'undefined' !== typeof someExpression`.]

Comment: No, they are *not* equivalent.

Comment: Any expression *except* that which consumes a Reference Specification Type (e.g typeof, del, lhs of =) will force variables/properties to be evaluated. It is during this evaluation that a ReferenceError may be raised.

Comment: Thx for having a deep look to Parsley code :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two approaches are almost the same, except one: `typeof` won't raise `ReferenceError: a is not defined` in case if `a` variable was not defined as a variable.

Say, `typeof` approach is just more fool-proof.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are equivalent if `undefined` has not been tampered with. The only reason `typeof` is preferred over direct comparison with undefined is because `undefined` can be redefined to be anything else like `undefined = 5`. Also as pointed out by VisioN a can raise a `ReferenceError` when your not checking in the context of function parameter but rather whether `a` is `defined globally`. In order to not get a `ReferenceError` when comparing directly to undefined in the global context you need to perform:

```
window.a === undefined
```