# Why do idiomatic.js and jQuery recommend `variable === undefined` for local variables

Tags: javascript, undefined

I was looking through [idiomatic.js](https://github.com/rwldrn/idiomatic.js/) and notice the following lines in the type checking secton:

#### undefined:

**Global Variables:**

```
typeof variable === "undefined"
```

**Local Variables:**

```
variable === undefined
```

This section appears to originally be based on the [jQuery style guide](http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/)

I'd been taught that the first form was safer since `undefined` can be redefined to another value.  I also don't know of any reason that the 1st form doesn't work for local variables.

It seems to work fine in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T5zab/).  Can anyone explain why this style makes sense?

```
var undefined = 2;

function test(){
  var x;
    
    alert("1: " + (typeof x == "undefined"));
    alert("2: " + ( x  === undefined)); 
    
}

test();  //alerts "1: true", then  "2: false"
```

Comment: The real reason behind #1 is to avoid a `ReferenceError`. There's no need to avoid that when testing local variables.

Comment: @Bergi thanks that second link was very helpful.  Makes sense if jQuery defines their own version of undefined.  Less sense that Idiomatic.js copied that as a general recommendation though.

Comment: I hate automatical deletion of edited dupe-comments. For future reference, the "second link" (and better duplicate) was [variable === undefined vs. typeof variable === “undefined”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725603/variable-undefined-vs-typeof-variable-undefined?lq=1)