# Underscore template Uncaught ReferenceError variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I am trying to render a basic backbone view with an underscore template, but I keep getting the following error when attempting to render the template.

**Uncaught ReferenceError: *amount* is not defined**

here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rkj6j36n/

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="msg-con"></div>
</body>
```

JS

```
DumbViewObj = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('.msg-con'),
    initialize:function(){
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        var template = _.template('I am <%= amount %> dumb',{amount:'200'});
        this.$el.append(template);
    },
});
var dumb = new DumbViewObj();
```

I'm sure the solution is something dead simple, but I can't figure it out

Comment: every thing seem's to be fine , used the exact same code http://jsfiddle.net/JQu5Q/7/

Comment: @aktiv-coder: You're using an old version of Underscore, the `_.tempate(template_string, template_data)` form is no longer supported.

Comment: Bergi's answer is spot-on - http://stackoverflow.com/q/16977178/104380

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because template is a function and template( obj ) returns the string you are after, it does not return the string after you call it.

What your code is doing

```
var xxx = template();
this.$el.append(xxx);
```

what you should be doing

```
render: function(){
    var template = _.template($('#dumb').html());
    var vars = {amount:200};
    var html = template(vars);
    this.$el.append(html);
},
```

Answer (score 5):

in one line:

```
this.$el.append(_.template('I am <%= amount %> dumb')({amount:200}))
```

Comment: this seems to be an outdated solution for an older underscore version

Answer (score 4):

[_.template](http://underscorejs.org/#template) compiles the template into a function. You have to pass the parameters to the resulting function to be evaluated:

```
    var template = _.template('I am <%= amount %> dumb');
    this.$el.append(template({amount:'200'}));
```

Comment: @aktiv-coder Sorry I have not enough reputation points for comments. Your snippet is working because you are using an older version of underscore. Try to use 1.7 instead.