# Checking for a numerical index in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, numeric

I'm receiving json data that is aggregated by numerical indexes.

When I'm in my forloop, for example, the index might start at 1, which means in my forloop an error would occur because 0 doesnt exist.

How do I check if a numerical index exists in the javascript array?

Comment: Lets see an example of this json data

Comment: How could an index *not* exist in an array? What you mean is it's value is `undefined`, right?

Comment: Please post an example. Descriptions of problems in questions are often difficult to answer without concrete examples.

Comment: You haven't posted any code for us to see why you would have an error, but as a suggestion, have you considered using [Array.prototyp.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)? This will most likely solve your problem (unless `Array.length` is broken) without you showing us any code. :/

Comment: This is a valid question. Arrays in JavaScript can be sparse. They're basically Objects with some special properties.

Comment: @acdcjunior I don't understand why the question has been closed because_it's difficult to tell what is being asked_. It's very clear what was asked. In a numeric array there can be gaps which have to be checked otherwise the script execution ends.

Comment: @PeterVARGA that's what I asked. If by "checking" he meant testing if the value is `undefined` or not. Or if he meant something else entirely (which, 7 years later, seems not to be the case).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
var a = [1, 2, 3], index = 2;

if ( a[index] !== void 0 ) { /* void 0 === undefined */
    /* See concern about ``undefined'' below.        */
    /* index doesn't point to an undefined item.     */
}
```

Comment: Or `if (index in a)` would technically check for existence, though your `!== undefined` check will most likely suffice.

Comment: typeof a[index] !== 'undefined' should be more safe

Comment: @Aubin Why? If `a` is not defined it will fail just as badly when trying to access `[index]`.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/4725603/1624376

Comment: @Aubin That second comment there, you have the string `'undefined'` a rather than `undefined`. Makes a tremendous difference in output :O

Comment: @Dan: your 'undefined' could be overridden by a local variable inside a scope, even in ES5. Unlikely but possible. ;)
`(function(undefined)
{
    var a = [1, 2, 3],
        index = 2;

    if ( a[index] !== undefined ) {
       console.log('Index #' + index + '=' + a[index]); /* never triggered, cuz undefined is set to 3. typeof a[index] !== 'undefined' is better*/

    }
})(3)`

Comment: @SammieFox if a developer creates a function with `undefined` as its parameter name, he's worthy of being skinned alive regardless of programming language used, and worthy of being boiled in tar afterwards if he's coding in JS. FWIW, I wouldn't go with `void 0` instead of `undefined` just for that reason - it's not "defensive coding", it's "paranoid coding" since ES5. `void 0` is semantic noise, `undefined` is semantically correct. We should program with humans in mind, not computers, IMVHO.

Comment: @vaxquis Setting undefined as an (undefined) parameter-value, was a recommend coding-style for IIFE-patterns, to make sure that the undefined-parameter is really undefined and not already defined outside the scope (e.g. by third-party-scripts). But yeah, its unneccassary since ES5 with strict mode.  https://books.google.de/books?id=IS0EAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA32&ots=ZNZQx-edVE&dq=iife%20undefined&hl=de&pg=PA32 ---- https://toddmotto.com/what-function-window-document-undefined-iife-really-means/

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to use `for(key in data)`

```
var data = [];
data[1] = 'a';
data[3] = 'b';

for(var index in data) {
  console.log(index+":"+data[index]);
}
//Output:
// 1-a
// 3-b
```

Which will loop over each key item in data if the indexes aren't contiguous.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are actually describing is an [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) rather than an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), but is array like in the fact that it has properties that are of [uint32_t](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29) but does not have essential [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property present. Then you could convert it to a real array like this. Browser compatibility wise this requires support of [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Javascript

```
function toArray(arrayLike) {
    var array = [],
        i;

    for (i in arrayLike) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(arrayLike, i) && i >= 0 && i <= 4294967295 && parseInt(i) === +i) {
            array[i] = arrayLike[i];
        }
    }

    return array;
}

var object = {
    1: "a",
    30: "b",
    50: "c",
},
array = toArray(object);

console.log(array);
```

Output

`[1: "a", 30: "b", 50: "c"`]`

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/VzFcS/)

Ok, now you have a sparsely populated array and want to use a `for` loop to do something.

Javascript

```
var array = [],
    length,
    i;

array[1] = "a";
array[30] = "b";
array[50] = "c";

length = array.length;
for (i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(array, i)) {
        console.log(i, array[i]);
    }
}
```

Ouput

```
1 "a"
30 "b"
50 "c"
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Ls7zE/)

Alternatively, you can use [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) if your browser supports it, or the available shim as given on the MDN page that I linked, or [es5_shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)

Javascript

```
var array = [];

array[1] = "a";
array[30] = "b";
array[50] = "c";

array.forEach(function (element, index) {
    console.log(index, element);
});
```

Output

```
1 "a"
30 "b"
50 "c"
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/98NPe/)