# check if array is both defined and has length

Tags: javascript, if-statement, performance

I have a javascript query like this that is meant to check both `undefined` arrays and `empty` arrays:

```
if(array){
    if(array.length > 0){
       function1();
    }else{
       function2();
    }
}else{
    function2();
}
```

I've tried something like

```
if(array && ( array.length > 0)){
    function1();
}else{
    function2();
}
```

but no dice, get a `variable is undefined` error. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in) doing `if(variable)` works just fine for this use-case, but this only works on strings rather than arrays. Is there any way to do two-in-one in javascript in a case like this?

Comment: `if(array && ( array.length > 0)){` should work fine. If you get an error, it's unrelated or `array` is not declared (maybe you get a `ReferenceError`?)

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4725603/255756). There are some approaches for determining whether a variable is not defined.

Comment: If you get a reference error, then I wonder where `array` is supposed to come from? As long as you are not integrating two independent scripts somehow, any variable should be at least declared. **Please provide more context.**

Answer (score 6):

> ...I get a variable is undefined error

That means `array` isn't declared *at all* anywhere. To defend against that, you can use `typeof`:

```
if (typeof array !== "undefined" && array && array.length > 0)
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ogiCUbo/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ogiCUbo/1/edit)

There's a difference between a symbol being completely undefined, and a defined symbol resolving to a variable that contains the value `undefined.` Confusing, but true. You can safely use `typeof` on anything, even something that is completely undeclared anywhere, but if you try to read the *value* of something that isn't declared anywhere, you'll get that `ReferenceError` saying it doesn't exist.

Comment: If you do `typeof array !== "undefined"`, I'd argue that the second test, `array`, is unnecessary.

Comment: @FelixKling: Yeah, although it could have the value `null`. Trying to read `length` from `null` would give us an error.

Comment: Forgot about `null` :-/ I should go to sleep.