# Checking for Undefined with `typeof ==` and `===`

Tags: javascript

I just read this excellent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) and top [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/409976) on "== versus ===".

```
var x = undefined;
```

When checking if `x` is truly equal to `undefined`, both of the below worked.

```
if(typeof x == "undefined") {
    console.log("typeof x == \"undefined\"");
}

if(x === undefined) {
    console.log("x === undefined");
}
```

output:

> typeof x == "undefined"
>
> x === undefined

Is one way more *idiomatic* than the other? If so, why?

Comment: You may want to look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725603/variable-undefined-vs-typeof-variable-undefined

Comment: This also may interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: Your second way may cause an error if `x` is not declared.

Answer (score 3):

I would say if you have control over the the range of possible values of `x` then checking for `x === undefined` is the most idiomatic way. For instance, if you have a function that is returning a result, or `undefined` if it encounters an error.

Otherwise, you should use `typeof x == 'undefined'`.

The caveat is that some expressions and variables can be `undefined` because they are simply not defined, while others are explicitly defined as `undefined`.

If you try to do this:

```
var x = undefined;
if(typeof x == "undefined") // This works
if(x === undefined) // This works
if(typeof y == "undefined") // This works
if(y === undefined) // This does not work and throws a ReferenceError
```

So basically, using `typeof` is safer and easier if you don't have control over the [variable's range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_%28computer_programming%29) because you don't have to implement exception handling.

Comment: So, adding the 6 characters (`typeof`) to improve safety seems well worth it. `if(typeof x === "undefined")`. Even if you *could* control the range, isn't it worth it since JavaScript gets interpreted rather than compiled?

Comment: @KevinMeredith At that point I would lean towards [the better performing code](http://jsperf.com/type-of-undefined-vs-undefined).

Answer (score 0):

Both the above conditional checks work, and therefore, can be used interchangeably. However, since you have asked about being *idiomatic*, I would say the conditional check: `typeof x == undefined` sounds better when reading and explains what the code really does, and hence, has my personal vote :)

Answer (score 0):

if you use raw javascript you'd better do `typeof x == "undefined"`, why?

because `undefined` is a global variable which, in some browsers is not read-only and anyone could override it, for instance, in Chrome 14, or Firefox 6 you can do:

```
window.undefined = "MyUndefined"
```

and this would override the `undefined` global variable, of course it seems so ridicules to do this or even to worry about this, but it is much more safer when you check your variables being undefined, like this:

```
typeof x == "undefined"
```

- this is the main reason why I'm against using the `undefined` property.

and what this has anything to do with using raw javascript:

if you use jQuery, jQuery has overrided the global variable `undefined` with a real `undefined` value.