# Can I use (undefined || null) to check if my variable is null or undefined?

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

In my Javascript code I'm checking if a variable is undefined (not the value undefined but the variable not defined) or null. To trim the code I'm using an operator. This is how I do it:

```
if (myVariable === (undefined || null)) {
    // Do something.
}
```

A friend of mine told me once, that I should rather split the checks into:

```
if (myVariable === undefined || myVariable === null) {
    // Do something.
}
```

Is there really any difference between these two approaches? If yes, which one should I use and why?

Comment: Lol... No, this won't work. Write a helper function like this: `function IsNullOrUndefined (obj) { return obj === null || typeof obj === 'undefined'; }`

Comment: @WoIIe: "this won't work" -- what "this"? The second will.

Comment: @zerkms Just everything ... The check if a `myVariable === undefined` doesn't check if myVariable is undefined. And since `(undefined || true)` will always return false, he is just checkinf if `myvariable === false` ...

Comment: @Wolle—"that" won't work either. If a variable hasn't been declared or initialised, attempting to access it's value will throw an error in the call to your function.

Comment: @WoIIe: "The check if a variable === undefined won't work" --- why do you think so? What if you try before you continue this pointless discussion?

Comment: @zerkms `var undefined = "lol"; var myVariable = "rofl"; if (myVariable === undefined) { }` ... Got it ?

Comment: @WoIIe: why would you redefine it? It makes no sense to do something stupid then use it as a justification for something else.

Comment: @zerkms You just DON'T check the type without the `typeof()` function ... Just don't do it ... This is not correct. Since `undefined` is a type in JavaScript, you need to check the type of your variable and not the value -.-#

Comment: @WoIIe: "Since undefined is a type in JavaScript" --- it's not only a type, but also a *value*. "This is not correct" --- who told you so? " You just DON'T check the type without the typeof() function" --- why don't you do the same for `null` then?

Comment: @zerkms The identity check `myVariable === undefined` would trigger the error "myVariable is not defined"... What's your damn problem? You just have to try it -.-#

Comment: @WoIIe: why would you work with a variable that is not declared? It's again - doing some stupid things to justify your opinion? "You just have to try it" --- I know how it works. I just don't see why you would do stupid things to make your life harder. I never redefine `undefined` and I never work with not declared variables. That is what professional programmers do, you should try it one day.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there really any difference between these two approaches?

Yes.

```
myVariable === (undefined || null)
```

is equivalent to

```
myVariable === null
```

which is only true if *myVariable* is *null*, and false if *myVariable* is *undefined*. Whereas:

```
myVariable === undefined || myVariable === null
```

returns true if *myVariable* is either *undefined* or *null*.

> If yes, which one should I use and why?

Neither (probably), even if the answer was yes. If you are trying to determine whether a variable exists or not, you can only test for global variables as they are properties of the global object:

```
// In global code
var window = this;

// Later…
if (varname in window) {
  // varname is a global variable or property
}
```

Within a function execution context, you can only reliably test for a variable using try..catch:

```
try {
  var blah = foo;
} catch (e) {
  // foo is probably not a variable in scope
}
```

But that is almost certainly not a good idea. See [JavaScript check if variable exists (is defined/initialized) - Which method is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-is-defined-initialized-which-method-is-b).

You should probably be doing:

```
if (typeof varname == 'undefined' || varname === null) {
  // varname either does't exist or has a value of undefined or null.
}
```

The tests need to be in that order so that if *varname* hasn't been declared or otherwise created, the *typeof* test fails before the *null* test, which would otherwise throw an error.

Answer (score 3):

Prefere : `if (typeof myVariable === "undefined" || myVariable === null) {`.

[variable === undefined vs. typeof variable === "undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725603/variable-undefined-vs-typeof-variable-undefined)

Because with `if (myVariable === undefined) {` your console can be return an error or warning.

Like this :

```
ReferenceError: myVariable is not defined
    if (myVariable === undefined) {
```

[image]

PS : `(undefined || null)` is always **null** (because *undefined* return **false**).

Comment: Why would you work with not declared variable? Isn't it stupid?

Comment: @zerkms Because I check if the variable is an undefined. undefined = not declared variable.

Comment: @Hors Sujet: nope. My question: why would someone write a code that checks a variable that is not declared. It's stupid. If you don't declare a variable - then you don't need to check if it's undefined. It's a parse time check, no reason to check it in runtime.

Comment: Exactly. Working with not declared variable doesn't make sense, but in my case I have to check if a variable is declared.

Comment: @dwettstein: cannot you just move your eyes up the code and tell if it's declared or not? That way you don't perform any checks in runtime.

Comment: @zerms Maybe `myVariable` is an property of an object like this `obj.myVariable`.

Comment: @Hors Sujet: if it's a property - then you use `'myVariable' in obj`, not comparison with `undefined`

Comment: @zerkms: Unfortunatly I can't. I'm programming in vCenter Orchestrator and the variables can be declared on several locations. Basically, we use the check for an undeclared variable for debugging reasons. If an undeclared variable occur, we forgot to add it.

Comment: @zerkms And I don't know, it isn't my question. But the answer don't be return an error.

Answer (score 2):

`===` operator in JS compares 2 operands (values).

In case of `myVariable === (undefined || null)` the operands are: `myVariable`, which represents the value it holds, and `(undefined || null)` which represents the value `null`, because operands (expressions) must be evaluated before comparison. And the `(undefined || null)` expression is evaluated to `null`.

So effectively your solution is identical to `myVariable === null`.

If you follow the same idea and evaluate your friend proposal you will see that his advice is correct.

Comment: Except that if *myVariable* is not defined, then `myVariable === undefined` will throw an error (and for the paranoid, *undefined* might have been assigned some other value), whereas `typeof myVariable == 'undefined'` does more or less the same test but does not (and prevents `myVariable === null` from throwing an error too). :-)

Comment: @RobG: "Except that if myVariable is not **declared**"

Comment: @zerkms—except that if *myVariable* has not been created by assignment, or declared, or included in formal parameter list. Is there a shorter expression? ;-) Maybe "if an identifier *myVariable* is not in scope"?

Comment: @RobG: if it is passed as a parameter - then `variable === undefined` will not throw an exception. It will only throw an exception if a variable **is not declared**.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `(undefined || null)` always evaluates to `null` so your first expression always false when `myVariable` is undefined. The second variant is do what you want correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. For your example, `undefined` is equal `false` then `null` is equal `false` too and this last value returns from expression. So this is why first approach is equal to `if (myVariable === null) { ... }`. The second approach is preferable, but if you not a 'JavaScript: The Good Parts' guy, you can stick with `if (myVariable == null) { ... }` or `if (myVariable == undefined) { ... }`.