# Karma: Can't find variable: exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, karma-runner, node-modules

I've written a node module which can be used for both the backend and client

```
(exports || window).Bar= (function () {
    return function () { .... }
})();
```

Now my karma tests use PhantomJs and complain about the not existing `exports` variable

```
gulp.task('test', function () {
    var karma = require('karma').server;

    karma.start({
        autoWatch: false,
        browsers: [
            'PhantomJS'
        ],
        coverageReporter: {
            type: 'lcovonly'
        },
        frameworks: [
            'jasmine'
        ],
        files: [
            'bar.js',
            'tests/bar.spec.js'
        ],
        junitReporter: {
            outputFile: 'target/junit.xml'
        },
        preprocessors: {
            'app/js/!(lib)/**/*.js': 'coverage'
        },
        reporters: [
            'progress',
            'junit',
            'coverage'
        ],
        singleRun: true
    });
});
```

The error I get is

```
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X) ERROR
   ReferenceError: Can't find variable: exports
```

Is there a way to ignore the exports variable in karam/phantomsJs ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common pattern is usually to check whether the `exports` variable is defined:

```
(function(){
  ...
  var Bar;
  if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    Bar = exports;
  } else {
    Bar = window.Bar = {};
  }
})();
```

This pattern is used [in Backbone](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js) as example - well, it's technically bit more complicated in the source code because it does support also AMD, but the idea it's this.

You can also push down the check passing it as first argument of the wrapping function:

```
(function(exports){

  // your code goes here

  exports.Bar = function(){
      ...
  };

})(typeof exports === 'undefined'? this['mymodule']={}: exports);
```

Have a look [at this blog post](http://caolanmcmahon.com/posts/writing_for_node_and_the_browser/) for more info.

Comment: Look at this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725603/variable-undefined-vs-typeof-variable-undefined