# ExpressJS - Send a response from middleware

Tags: node.js, express

For every request that happens, I'd like to check if a parameter in the query string is set. If not, the application should send a certain message; otherwise, route as appropriate.

In `app.js`:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    if(req.query.key === undefined) {
        res.send("Sorry!");
    }
    req.db = db;
    next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
```

When `'/'` is requested without the param, `Sorry!` is displayed. However, my ExpressJS app crashes with this error:

`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

I'm not entirely sure why this is happening. I've tried moving the check to the route itself in `index.js`, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because you're still continuing on with the execution and calling `next()`, which moves onto the next middleware or route in the stack.

Return early to stop it from moving onto the next middleware.

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    if(req.query.key === undefined) {
        //return out of the function here
        return res.send("Sorry!");
    }
    req.db = db;
    next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. For some reason I assumed that `res.send()` was essentially equivalent to a return statement.

Comment: @cmlndz In that case, `if(req.query.key)` is perfectly fine, no need for strict type checking. Plus the above method is valid, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725603/variable-undefined-vs-typeof-variable-undefined Even if there's no query parameter, `req.query` is always defined.

Comment: @BenFortune you are right about req.query (perhaps I was dragging this from and old version of express). thnx