# Undefined object property not equals to `undefined`

Tags: javascript

I've found that undefined object property not equals to `undefined`.

```
if (obj.unexistingProperty === undefined) {
  // condition is false
}

if (typeof obj.unexistingProperty === 'undefined') {
  // condition is true
}
```

While debugger consoles (Firebug and Chrome dev tools) consider both conditions true.

What is the explanation for that?

---

As it turned out, the code took place inside of

```
function (undefined) {
  ...
}
```

that shadowed `undefined` in local scope.

Comment: Could you have mistakenly redefined `undefined`?

Comment: @icktoofay is that even possible? chrome console wont let me

Comment: [Both conditions are true](http://jsfiddle.net/j2x2q7wb/).

Comment: @Jorg It's possible in older versions of JavaScript, but not in ES5. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4726848/2234742) in the suggested duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that, @icktoofay ! Indeed, it was redefined with anonymous 'function (undefined, prop)', which I mistakenly considered a safe way to define waste callback arguments. You may file it as an answer if the question will be unmarked as duplicate.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister The global  `undefined` property can no longer be redefined, but can be shadowed with a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens, `undefined` isn’t a keyword like `null` is—`undefined`, before ECMAScript 5, can be redefined to something else. If you’ve mistakenly set it to something else, like the number `5`, then test something *actually* undefined against it for equality, you’ll pretty clearly end up with `false`. On the other hand, `typeof` ignores local bindings.

If you can avoid redefining `undefined`, that would be for the best. Other things you can do would be testing for equality against `void 0` (`void` takes an expression, discards its value, and returns the real `undefined`) or, as prompted the question, use `typeof` to check for `undefined` instead.