# Difference between two if statements

Tags: javascript

Today i caught myself writing the following two lines of code:

```
if (typeof a === 'undefined') { ... }

if (a === undefined) { ... }
```

and i was asking myself what exactly the difference is.

Is there any actual difference between these two approaches on checking if a variable is undefined?

Comment: `===` compares the values along with types of a variable, there is no difference

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725603/variable-undefined-vs-typeof-variable-undefined)

Comment: The typeof operator returns a string which will define the type of the value you are evaluating.

In this scenario if the var you are evaluating is  '31' you can say:

    if(typeof var === 'number'){ returns true}


The == operator will compare for equality. The === operator will not do the conversion, if two values are not the same type === will simply return false