# value === undefined vs typeof value === 'undefined' in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, auth0

I have little confusion in this. I am using Auth0 and writing rules which uses node.js syntax. Now I read somewhere that the right way to check undefined value in node is `typeof value === 'undefined'` but `value === undefined` also work in node. So what is the main difference in both of them?

Comment: If `value` is *undeclared* the second way would throw a ReferenceError. But other than that, it's the same thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725603/variable-undefined-vs-typeof-variable-undefined Please see if this helps.

Comment: @vlaz You mean the first way would throw too ..?

Comment: @MayankParnami, aah sorry. My bad